# Throwing exceptions with jdbc query

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following repository method:

```
@Override
public List<Item> getItemsByName(String name) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE NAME = :name";
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new ItemMapper());
}
```

Now I want to throw ItemsNotFoundException when user passed item name that not exists. How should I do it? Should I throw exception when query() method return empty list or is null:

```
List<Item> items = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new ItemMapper());
if (items == null || items.isEmpty()) {
    throw new ItemsNotFoundException();
}
return items;
```

Or should I throw this exception when I will get DataAccessException:

```
try {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new ItemMapper());
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    throw new ItemNotFoundException();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing in a name that doesn't exist won't result in a `DataAccessException`, so that won't work. There's nothing exceptional about an empty result for a query.

However why do you want to throw an exception if the results are empty? Is it an exceptional case for you (i.e. it's a bug that someone would search for a name that doesn't exist)? If so, it's a valid approach. In the general sense an empty list would probably be better.

Comment: Agreed. Throwing exception for empty list is business logic, and doesn't belong in DAO class.